# How to Specify Multiple Patterns for Delimiter In Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, java.util.scanner, delimiter

so I have a method that copies one file to another with the use of a delimiter that removes the "null(U)" references, and the input file looks like...

```
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image2.jpeg;image0;null(U) keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4,
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image3.jpeg;image1;null(U) keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4,
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image4.jpeg;image2;null(U) keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4,
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image5.jpeg;image3;null keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4,
```

...and the output file looks like...

```
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image2.jpeg;image0;keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4,
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image3.jpeg;image1;keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4,
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image4.jpeg;image2;keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4,
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image5.jpeg;image3;null keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4,
```

And for the small chunk of code regarding my delimiter, I have...

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(inputFile);
reader.useDelimiter("null\\(U\\) ");
```

However, I was wondering, if I wanted to specify multiple patterns which the delimiter should look for (i.e. in addition to "null (U)", I wanted to add "null"), how would I go about doing that? I've seen a few examples online, but I'm still not sure how the delimiter is able to distinguish between the various patterns. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex and create a pattern with something like :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("your regex here");
```

and then give that pattern to the `useDelimiter(p)` method.

The regex could be something like `(null\\s)|(null\\(U\\)\\s)`

Comment: Even with that, how would I specify multiple patterns? Meaning, how would it differentiate between "null (U)" and "null"?

Comment: well you want the same thing to happen if it's null(U) or just null? then a regex will allow you to declare as many delimiters as you want to and use the first it encounters in the string.

Comment: just specify every delimiters between `()` in your regex

Comment: What if those nulls are actually strings?

Comment: well `(null)` represents the string "null" and `\0` a null value

Comment: When I tried just `(null)` eclipse recognized it as an actual null reference, not a string. That's why I'm asking :P

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2071/discussion-between-talnicolas-and-this-0ne-pr0grammer)